# Is the tabbing sequence logical?in HTML

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Hi I am facing a very hard issue regarding tab order for accessibility.My tabs are functioned through jquery.ui.min.js. Tab order,classes & function are coming from there.Although all tabs are functioning properly but when i validate i am getting accessibility issue.Please suggest me other way.

I am looking for accessibility point of view only.One more thing this library adding blank style (style="") on every element.How can i remove it Please suggest.

```html
<div class="tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="padding: 10px;">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="">
    <li tabindex="0" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" aria-controls="tab-content4" aria-selected="true" style="z-index: 2147483646;"><a href="#tab-content4" title="test" class="ui-tabs-anchor" tabindex="0" id="ui-id-1" style="">tab1</a></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" aria-controls="tab-content1" aria-selected="false" style=""><a href="#tab-content1" title="abc" class="ui-tabs-anchor" tabindex="0" id="ui-id-2" style="">tab2</a></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" aria-controls="tab-content2" aria-selected="false" style=""><a href="#tab-content2" title="Cde" class="ui-tabs-anchor" tabindex="0" id="ui-id-3" style="">tab3</a></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" aria-controls="tab-content3" aria-selected="false" style=""><a href="#tab-content3" title="efg" class="ui-tabs-anchor" tabindex="0" id="ui-id-4" style="">tab4</a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="#tab-content4">Others</a></li> -->
  </ul>
  <strong style=""> <a class="fl_r" href="#" style="">Subscribe
 </a></strong>

  <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="">
    <table class="ui-table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody style="">

        <tr style="">
          <td>test1</td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <table class="ui-table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody style="">

        <tr style="">
          <td>test2</td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test21</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test22</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <table class="ui-table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody style="">

        <tr style="">
          <td>test3</td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test31</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test32</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <table class="ui-table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody style="">

        <tr style="">
          <td>test4</td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test41</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="">
          <td>test42</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <!-- <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content">&amp;nbsp;</div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: What are you using to validate accessibility?

Comment: I am using a chrome plugin that is site improve.

Comment: Is that the full report? "Accessibility issue"?

Comment: yes it is .Actually the issue is coming particularly this section only.it is dummy code.

Comment: Can you post the actual issue being reported by the tool?

Answer (score 0):

When running the siteimprove plugin, you will get a "review" item (not an "error" or "warning") for any element that has a `tabindex` specified.  Or at least that's what my testing is showing.

[image: screenshot of siteimprove warning]

[image: screenshot of siteimprove details regarding the warning]

It doesn't seem to matter if valid tabindex values of 0 or -1 are used.  I would expect a "review" or "warning" if tabindex were greater than 0 since that's highly discouraged in the [html spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute).

> **Warning!**
> Using a positive value for `tabindex` to specify the element’s position in the [sequential focus navigation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation) order interacts with the order of all focusable elements. It is error-prone, and therefore not recommended. Authors should generally leave elements to appear in their default order.

So siteimprove is being a bit overzealous and flagging every use of `tabindex` as a review candidate.

Note that in your example, the `tabindex="0"` on all the <a> elements is not necessary (*).  They are already in the tab sequence.

(*) If an anchor (<a>) does **not** have an `href` attribute, then the anchor is **not** a tabstop and **would** need a `tabindex="0"` if you wanted focus to move to the element.  However, the anchor would also need a keyboard and mouse event handler to handle clicks since an anchor without an href does not handle any events.

The code sample is also a little weird in that the list item (<li>) has a `tabindex="0"` **and** the nested link in that list item allows focus.  That's two tab stops for essentially the same element.  That would be an accessibility issue.